# How to charge product of numbers in BST tree?

Tags: c++

I wrote template which charge product numbers in BST tree, but console show me any problem in main. I don't have a idea how resolve this problem. I hope that someone show me where I did error. I think that template is OK, and I make any error in main but I don't see this error. I will gratefull if someone show me this error.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


template<typename TData>
class BST {
    public:
        class BSTNode {
            public:
                BSTNode(const TData& d):left(NULL),right(NULL),data(d)
                {};
                BSTNode *left, *right;
                TData data;
        };

    protected:
        typedef BSTNode* PBSTNode;
        PBSTNode root;

    private:
        bool Insert_tmp(PBSTNode &ptr,const TData &d);
        void PreOrder_tmp(PBSTNode ptr)const;
        void InOrder_tmp(PBSTNode ptr)const;
        void PostOrder_tmp(PBSTNode ptr)const;
        void DeleteTree(PBSTNode &ptr);
        int Iloczyn(PBSTNode ptr);

    public:
        BST();
        BST(const BST<TData>&); // aby zablokować konstruktor kopiujący nie implementujemy go
        bool Insert(const TData& d);
        void PreOrder()const;
        void InOrder()const;
        void PostOrder()const;
        bool Delete(const TData& d);
        int Iloczyn();
        ~BST();
};


template<typename TData>
BST<TData>::BST()
{
    root=NULL;
}

template<typename TData>
bool BST<TData>::Insert(const TData& d)
{
    return Insert_tmp(root,d);
}

template<typename TData>
void BST<TData>::PreOrder()const
{
    if( root != NULL )
    {
        std::cout<<root->data<<", ";
        PreOrder_tmp(root->left);
        PreOrder_tmp(root->right);
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
}

template<typename TData>
void BST<TData>::InOrder()const
{
    if( root != NULL )
    {
        InOrder_tmp(root->left);
        std::cout<<root->data<<", ";
        InOrder_tmp(root->right);
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
}

template<typename TData>
void BST<TData>::PostOrder()const
{
    if( root != NULL )
    {
        PostOrder_tmp(root->left);
        PostOrder_tmp(root->right);
        std::cout<<root->data<<", ";
        std::cout<<std::endl;
    }
}

template<typename TData>
bool BST<TData>::Delete(const TData& d)
{
    PBSTNode    parent, //rodzic
                del,    //usuwany
                rem;    //zamienny

    parent = NULL;
    del=root;

    while( del != NULL && del->data != d )
    {
        parent=del;
        if( d < parent->data )
            del=del->left;
        else
            del=del->right;
    }

    // czy jest d na drzewie
    if( del == NULL )
        return false;

    // znaleziono element d


    if( del->left == NULL && del->right == NULL ) // przypadek: lisc
    {
        if( parent != NULL )
        {
            if( parent->data > del->data )
                parent->left=NULL;
            else
                parent->right=NULL;
        }
        else
            root == NULL;

        delete del;
    }
    else
    {
        if ( del->left == NULL || del->right == NULL ) // jedno poddrzewo
        {
            if( del->left == NULL )
                rem = del->right;
            else
                rem = del->left;
            *del=*rem;
        }
        else // są oba poddrzewa
        {
            parent = del;
            rem = del->left;
            while( rem->right != NULL )
            {
                parent = rem;
                rem = rem->right;
            }

            del->data = rem->data;

            if( parent == del )
                parent->left = rem->left;
            else
                parent->right = rem->left;
        }
        delete rem;
    }
    return true;
}

template<typename TData>
BST<TData>::~BST()
{
    if( root != NULL )
        DeleteTree(root);
}

template<typename TData>
bool BST<TData>::Insert_tmp(PBSTNode &ptr,const TData &d)
{
        if( ptr == NULL )
        {
            PBSTNode tmp;
            try
            {
                tmp=new BSTNode(d); // jezeli nie bedzie miejsca w pamieci to wystai tu wyjatek
                ptr=tmp;

                return true;
            }
            catch(...)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (d < ptr->data)
        {
            return Insert_tmp(ptr->left,d);
        }
        else if ( d > ptr->data )
        {
            return Insert_tmp(ptr->right,d);
        }
        else
        {
            return false; // gdy jest juz wartosc d w drzewie, w tej implementacji nie wstawiamy dwa razy tej samej wartosc
        }
}

template<typename TData>
void BST<TData>::PreOrder_tmp(PBSTNode ptr)const
{
    if( ptr != NULL )
    {
        std::cout<<ptr->data<<", ";
        PreOrder_tmp(ptr->left);
        PreOrder_tmp(ptr->right);
    }
}

template<typename TData>
int BST<TData>::Iloczyn(PBSTNode ptr)
{
    if(ptr==NULL)
    return 1;
    else
        return (ptr->PBSTNode *Iloczyn(ptr->left)*Iloczyn(ptr->right));


}

template<typename TData>
void BST<TData>::InOrder_tmp(PBSTNode ptr)const
{
    if( ptr != NULL )
    {
        InOrder_tmp(ptr->left);
        std::cout<<ptr->data<<", ";
        InOrder_tmp(ptr->right);
    }
}

template<typename TData>
void BST<TData>::PostOrder_tmp(PBSTNode ptr)const
{
    if( ptr != NULL )
    {
        PostOrder_tmp(ptr->left);
        PostOrder_tmp(ptr->right);
        std::cout<<ptr->data<<", ";
    }
}

template<typename TData>
void BST<TData>::DeleteTree(PBSTNode &ptr)
{
    if( ptr != NULL )
    {
        DeleteTree(ptr->left);
        DeleteTree(ptr->right);
        //cout<<"Del: "<<ptr->data<<", ";
        delete ptr;
    }
}


int main()
{
     cout << "Drzewa BST" << endl;

    BST<int> drzewo;

    drzewo.Insert(5);
    drzewo.Insert(-2);
    drzewo.Insert(13);
    drzewo.Insert(1);
    drzewo.Insert(0);
    drzewo.Insert(-2);
    drzewo.Insert(14);

    drzewo.PreOrder();
    cout<<drzewo.Iloczyn();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: undefined reference to BST<int>::Iloczyn() and ld returned 1 exit status. This errors show in main next to cout<<drzewo.Iloczyn();

Comment: Yes, you haven't implemented `template<typename TData> int BST<TData>::Iloczyn()`

Comment: I see this code and I really don't know what I must do, I see and I think that everything is Ok

Comment: `ptr->PBSTNode` looks like you misspelled `ptr->data`.

Comment: @MateuszWojno I _think_ I've covered everything you asked about in my answer but if I didn't, can you please clarify your question?

Answer (score 0):

In the `BST` definition you have declared the member function `int Iloczyn();` but you haven't implemented it.

You need to add this:

```
template<typename TData>
int BST<TData>::Iloczyn() {
    return 0;                  // or whatever int you'd like to return
}
```

You should however **not** return an `int` from this function. The node type is `TData` so you should return a `TData`.

The multiplication process in `Iloczyn()` will always return `1` because you never include the current node's data value in the multiplication.

These problems and a lot of other things are corrected in this [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/kxzBB6).

Ps. Don't `typedef` pointer types. It only makes it hard to read.

Comment: We don't know anything about what errors you get. Do you get compilation errors or runtime errors? For me, adding the above makes the program both compile and run without problems: [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/q_8fMD)

Comment: I added your code, and now a program don't show me errors but template returned me 0 and later I removed 0 from tree and added 2 a program still return 0.

Comment: @MateuszWojno I don't know what you expect the function to return so I just put `0` in the function. I made a comment on the line. Change that line so that it returns what you'd like it to return.

Comment: template<typename TData>
int BST<TData>::Iloczyn() {

    if(root==NULL)
    return 1;
    else
        return (root->PBSTNode *Iloczyn(root->left)*Iloczyn(root->right)); 
}                                                                                                                                                         Now a program show me many more errors.

Comment: @MateuszWojno I fixed the problems I think you talked about. If you discover more problems after this, please post a new question here at SO.